# Django `get_or_build` similar to `get_or_create`?

Tags: python, django

I'm curious if there's a way to do something conceptually like a "get_or_build" for an object, without saving it (yet), so you can reference itself to set a field before saving. Similar to Ruby's find_or_create_by or find_or_initialize_by with a block.

For instance, given the following model:

```
class User(models.Model):
  unique_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4)
  first_name = models.CharField()
  last_name = models.CharField()
  meta = models.CharField()
```

and an example of creating a User

```py
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe")
```

let's say I wanted to also set the `meta` column to whatever the default value for `unique_id` is in this situation, on initialization. I would have to do something like this, since it would be available when initializing the object:

```py
user = User.objects.filter(first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe").last()
if not user:
  user = User(first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe")
  user.meta = user.unique_id
  user.save()
```

is there anything like:

```py
user, built = User.objects.get_or_build(first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe")
if built:
  user.meta = user.uuid
  user.save
```

or a way to reference from within `get_or_create`:

```py
user = User.objects.get_or_create(first_name="Jane", last_name="Doe", meta=self.unique_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly You just want to create empty model object and fill it with specific data. So.

This will create object without saving it to Datbase

```
item = User() #Create empty user Object

# Fill Object with some data
item.first_name = "John"
item.last_name = "Doe"
item.meta = "Lorem ipsum"
```

And tihis will save it:

```
item.save() #Save/Create object to database
```

But generally it is not a good practice to modify Django's User model :)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model

Better would be to create `Userd_data` model with `User` as a `ForeignKey`

Hope it helps.

Comment: User was just an example (and apparently a bad/misleading one).  :)   One of my snippets above does just this (creates the empty object), this is more about the convenience of being able to copy a default attribute during create in one step. I just wasn't sure if there was anything available to do such a thing. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: But you have an default attributes before saving object :)

item = User()
print(item.unique_id) 

should work and print you item's unique ID.

Comment: Yep, and I get that. I was just trying to see if there was another way to accomplish it in one step without doing the initialize/save.